# How to import SAS7BDAT database to Stata without SAS

Tags: sas, stata

Is there a way to import `SAS7BDAT` files to Stata without SAS?
`usesas` requires SAS.

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted. I know someone have made a SAS table viewer in PowerShell, guess that could be rewritten to export to CSV instead.

Comment: what code do you want? if i knew the code i wouldn't ask the question. i did a research- that's why i wrote about usesas! it was a solution that did not work for me.

Comment: I am guessing at why you were downvoted; I have no way of knowing 5 individual reasons from 5 people (to date). Please don't shoot at the journalist. The larger point is that this is a programming forum, so many members feel that questions without code don't belong here at all, as they are about how to use software, not how to write programs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering myself:

You can import SAS file to R using `sas7bdat` library, and from R import to Stata.

import to R:

```
 install.packages("sas7bdat")
 library("sas7bdat")
 data = read.sas7bdat("file_name.sas7bdat")
```

save dta file:

```
 library(foreign)
 write.dta(data, "stata_file_name.dta")
```

Answer (score 0):

[This blog](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2012/04/12/build-your-own-sas-data-set-viewer-using-powershell/) describes how to export a SAS dataset using PowerShell

Comment: Thank you! i found it easier to do it via R.

Answer (score 0):

SAS Universal Viewer (freely available from SAS website) allows exporting to csv files if I'm not mistaken. Then importing the csv file from Stata should be straightforward enough.